# MySQL bulk replace a character with a space

Tags: mysql

As I understand it, the `REPLACE()` function in `MySQL` requires a `string` to be provided.
Unfortunately, I have around **16000** records that contain a `,` in various positions within the actual string.

I'd like to replace `,` with an empty `space` (space key, on the keyboard).

How could that be done in `MySQL`?

Update:

Examples:

```
'Dn 65-B, Km 2 + 770'
'Suciu Ioan, doctor'
'Curtici-Dorobanti, Dj 792'
```

Comment: Can you please explain the issue more, and/or add examples? Can't you do `replace(column, ',', ' ')` or are only some commas supposed to be replaced? What mysql version are you using?

Comment: @user3783243 You can supply the entire column? I got confused of the examples I saw on w3school - they list specific strings like: `SELECT REPLACE("SQL Tutorial", "SQL", "HTML");` - so I thought to myself - I'm not going to run 16K replace queries putting each said string that contains a `,` in. MySQL - the last version of the community server. The strings in question contain only 1 `,` that I need replaced with a space. Added some examples ^_^

Comment: Replace (oh a pun) replace the first parameter with the column name that contains the string to replace. `set colname = replace( colname, ',', ' ')`

Comment: @t1f Yes, first parameter is a value (column or string) to replace. That is the case for most functions, column or string can be used. You also can use it safely in a `select` to see how it will perform. It won't update unless used in an `UPDATE`.

Comment: @user3783243 Wish those w3 tutorials were more explicit with column/bulk examples also. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example

```
SELECT REPLACE("SQL Tutorial", "SQL", "HTML")
```

Replace the first parameter with the column name that contains the string to replace. Oh and this should go in an update statement

```
UPDATE tablename set colname = replace( colname, ',', ' ');
```

Although if you want to check what will happen, you could always run it as a select to start with, just to make sure

```
SELECT colname, replace( colname, ',', ' ') as theResult
FROM tablename 
LIMIT 20;
```

Comment: Yup, worked. Guess I need to think out of the box more, I took that example too literally thinking you can't provide an entire column -_- thanks for the help!